# Shopify Number of Decimals

Tags: shopify, bitcoin

I want to set up a shopify shop that only accepts Bitcoin. Only thing missing at the moment is that all currencies are only displayed with two decimals.

This doesn't work for Bitcoin and I am looking for a solution to show more decimals. Did anyone find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Have fun with this one! If you try three decimal places for a price on something, it will convert to higher values.. in Shopify, this is normal:

```
1.00 = 1.00
1.000 = 10.00
1.0000 = 100.00
1.00000 = 1000.00
```

Etc etc... do be careful therefore when you examine pricing and Bitcoin...